# Exporting a variable from script.js to App.svelte

Tags: javascript, import, export, svelte

So I have  a javascript file called `script.js` and it contains a variable `number`. I also have a svelte application that I am trying to export `number` to so that it can be used (and be reactive) in `App.svelte`. Any help doing this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a callback in your App.svelte to pass a variable from script.js to your App.svelte. And use an assignment in your App.svelte to make it reactive in App.

Comment: Remember a variable in a es-module will be shared and is initialized once.  But you can use a closure in script.js module to create your own instance.

Comment: @voscausa could you write your comments as an answer with example code in order to readers to better understand your solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things in your question:

1. If you export a variable from js-file, it’ll be read-only no matter how you define it (const or let)
2. If you want to a variable to be reactive in svelte, the variable must be defined in .svelte-file and then an assignment to it will be observed (ie. var = “value”)

You can solve the first problem by defining a setter-function in your script.js:

```
let number = 0
export const setNb = (value) => {number = value}
```

The second problem requires you to define a variable in .svelte-file and then assign a value to it. The changes in variable are reactive:

```
<script>
let num = 0
</script>
<h1 on:click={()=>num=num+1}>click to add. Nb:{num}</h1>
```

Basically you can update a variable in other .js-file, but to make it’s changes be reactive you must use local .svelte-variable.

The best solution for this problem is to use svelte **store**.

Here is REPL that shows these different cases:

https://svelte.dev/repl/dd241487e2424d5b9d93fb9fbdd23b6c?version=3.24.1

Answer (score 0):

In your module script.js:

```
export onNum(callback) {
  afterUpdate(() => {  // or another way to detect / signal a num change here
    callback(num); 
  });
};
```

In your App.svelte:

```
let num = 0;
onNum((n) => num = n);
```

Note: an es6 module is static and a kind of singleton. It will run once. When script will be used by other components num is shared and will not be initialized again. If you need sharing num it's ok. You can also use a closure or a class to create instances (instance variables).

I'have used the above approach to handle the result of multiple svelte actions like field validations and handle table search (and mark) results.